# Multiple redirects with 301 htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I am new to redirects and regex. I have an issue with redirects implemented. Here is the example. I want

```
http://www.example.com/support             redirect to
https://www.example.com/support/
```

But here is what happens

```
http://www.example.com/support             redirects to
https://www.example.com/support            redirects to
https://www.example.com/support/
```

Below is the htaccess contents for it

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# To remove double slash in the middle
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)//(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1/$2/

# redirect index.php to root
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.php$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301] 

#index to root
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules t avoid multiple redirecects:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

## Adding a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

# To remove double slash anywhere
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s[^?]*//
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0 [R=302,L,NE]

# redirect index.php to parent
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Make sure to use a new browser for testing.

Comment: Thank you! The given example works. however below does not work
`https://www.example.com/support/abc/index.php       redirects to https://www.example.com/support/abc                       & then redirects to 
https://www.example.com/support/abc/`

Comment: could you please he;lp

Comment: Nope. This did not work too. It adds additional trailing slash instead of removing index.php
`https://www.example.com/index.php    301 redirect to 
 https://www.example.com/index.php/`

Comment: This will redirect `https://www.example.com/support/abc/index.php` to `https://www.example.com/support/abc/` if you're seeing anything else then it might be due to old browser cache.

Comment: I have posted as an answer with images. Thank you

Comment: Updated it further. Can you test `https://www.example.com/support/abc/index.php` in a browser.

Comment: Nope... I have attached the additional image in the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172779/discussion-between-anubhava-and-saranya-thirumeni).

Answer (score 0):

@anubhava your edit shows the attachment 1[image: Your code]

The existing code in the question I posted does below 
[image: existing htaccess]

However, I am looking for a single redirect to the final destination..

Recent update by adding trailing slash results are below
[image: Recent edit - trailing slash]